# Testing the PayPal Adaptive Paymemts API in the Sandbox

Tags: paypal

I want to simulate a simple scenario with the adaptive API. A seller, buyer and my app.
I created 3 test accounts in the Sandbox website:

Account named buyer - of type Personal.
Account named seller - of type Business.
Account named myApp - of type Business.

I am using the Adaptive Payments C#.Net code samples from paypal developers site. (The code I am using is inside csharp_nv_adaptivepayments.zip ,  in the Pay.cs file).

I changed **sAPIUser**, **sAPIPassword**, **sAPISignature** to match myApp (From API Credentialns page in SandBox site)

I changed **sReceiverEmail** to the seller email.
I changed **sSenderEmail** to the buyer email.

After sending the request to https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay , 
and getting the response with sResponse = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd();  I get an OK status and I have a payKey in my hand.

Now, as the AdaptivePayments PDF says (P. 70) I need to redirect the user to 
https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=value , So I use Response.Redirect()   to this url. When the browser loads the page, I get a java script error in: 
var sf = new PAYPAL.AP.Subflow(); 
Stating that "Object doesn't support this action".

I tried to change the url to http://www.sanbox.paypal....paykey=value but then I just get a white page , saying "Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features."
Also, in both cases i didn't see any payment activity in the seller,buyer logs. 
What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yaron,

To make Live API calls, you need to obtain a Live APP ID from PayPal,
For making sandbox calls, you need to properly set up the sandbox testing environment, AND be logged in to it beforehand.

This guide explains in detail what you need to do for each case:
<del>Requires x.com free registration</del>

<del>http://www.x.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/211264-21046/HelloMoney.zip</del>

---

**EDIT**
X.com died a while back. I've posted my original files in GitHub:

`https://github.com/lmarkus/AdaptivePaymentsExample`

Comment: That file can't able to download

Comment: Yeah, that link died along with X.com two years ago.
Lucky for you, I'm a hoarder when it comes to my files.
I've published the example to GiHub.com.
Caveat though: This stuff is old!!!  Tread carefully.

I'd strongly suggest looking at the new REST API's unless you have an advanced use case.